# Get names and visibility of all columns

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatables and trying to get name and visibility of all columns in a table?

I have tried:

```js
$( 'table' ).DataTable().columns().every( function () {
  console.log( this.data() )
} );
```

It prints all the data in the table, but I don't know how to access the column names and visibility instead of `data()`.

I have looked both at [`column().nodes()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().nodes()) and [`columns().every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()) but I cannot find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`column().visible()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.visible%28%29) to get column visibility and [`column().header()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.header%28%29) to get `th` node for the column which you can use to get text in the header.

For example, consider the code below to get every column data, visibility and header text:

```
$( 'table' ).DataTable().columns().every( function () {
   // Column data
   console.log("Column data", this.data() );

   // Column visibility
   console.log("Column visibility", this.visible() );

   // Column header
   console.log("Column header", $(this.header()).text() );
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LxLvL20j/) for code and demonstration.